# Proving if $a_1\equiv b_1\pmod{n}$ and $a_2\equiv b_2\pmod{n}$ then we have $a_1+a_2\equiv b_1+b_2\pmod{n}$.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, proof-writing

How can I prove  if $a_1\equiv b_1\pmod{n}$ and $a_2\equiv b_2\pmod{n}$ then we have $a_1+a_2\equiv b_1+b_2\pmod{n}$? I have tried several ideas I've found online but don't really understand them. Is there a simple proof for this?

Comment: Try starting with a1=k*n+c and b1=j*n+c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a_1 \equiv b_1 \pmod n$ means that $a_1 - b_1$ is divisible by $n$ which means there exists an integer $k$ such that $a_1 - b_1 = kn$ and similarly, there exists an integer $q$ such that $a_2 - b_2 = qn$. So what you need to prove is that these two equations imply $a_1 + a_2 \equiv b_1 + b_2 \pmod n$ or in another words, that they imply that $(a_1 + a_2) - (b_1 + b_2)$ is divisible by $n$. So you're tying to show there exists an integer $j$ such that $(a_1 + a_2) - (b_1 + b_2) = jn$. Notice that

$$(a_1 + a_2) - (b_1 + b_2) = (a_1 - b_1) + (a_2 - b_2) = kn + qn = (k + q)n$$

And so setting $j = k + q$ we're done.

Answer (score 3):

For some integers $k,j$

$$a_1=kn+b_1$$

$$a_2=jn+b_2$$

What if you sum those up? You get

$$a_1+a_2=(k+j)n+(b_1+b_2)$$

Can you see what the above implies?

Comment: Could you elaborate? I really can't see where this is going.

Comment: Added something, @mino.

Comment: I am following everything you're doing, but not really see where to go from these steps to relate it to the problem.

Comment: @mino: What does it mean that $a\equiv b\pmod{n}$?

Comment: That a is congruent to b modulo n; that they share the same remainder for division of n.